# How to refer to a Django model in Sphinx docs?

Tags: django, python-sphinx

I have in my `conf.py` of Sphinx

```
intersphinx_mapping = {
    'django': ('http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/', 'http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_objects/'),
    # 'python': ('https://docs.python.org/3.5', None),
    }
```

Now I am trying to refer to a Django model:

```
"""For Django :django:class:`django.forms.fields.ChoiceField`."""
```

It does not produce the right thing in the HTML.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [objects.inv not available for intersphinx](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10315):

```
intersphinx_mapping = {
    'django': ('https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/',
               'https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_objects/'),
}
```

Then in docs, either of these will work:

```
:class:`~django.forms.ChoiceField`

:class:`django.forms.ChoiceField`
```

Which I found through [this search of their repo](https://github.com/django/django/search?l=Text&q=ChoiceField).